# How to set a PHP session variable through linux command prompt?

Tags: linux, php

How to set a PHP session variable through linux command prompt?

**Clarification**

So, as you know we can set session variables in PHP using $_SESSION global variable when coding.  I would like to know if there is a way to set this variable through php command prompt?

For example, in the code, if I can set $_SESSION['temp'] = "whatever"

Is there a way to set the same variable through command prompt PHP?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you will get a more complete answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this is going to be Linux-specific

Comment: Who's session are you setting ?

Comment: I'm writing a very specific command line application (or trying to) that automates a few tasks, that requires this operation.  It is my own session for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's default session handler stores the session data in `serialize()` format in a file, which means it's basically plain-text. You could certainly manipulate that file from the command line, using any of the standard unix text manipulation tools (perl, sed, awk, even echo/cat in a shell script, etc...), as long as you don't introduce a syntax error into the serialized data.

But at that point, unless you find a function/library/module that does `unserialize()` and most likely `serialize()` as well, you might as well just PHP itself to do the manipulation. It'd be a pretty rare system that doesn't have the CLI version of PHP installed alongside the webserver version.

```
$dat = file_get_contents('/path/to/session/file');
$session = unserialize($dat);
$session['temp'] = 'whatever';
$dat = serialize($session);
file_put_contents('/path/to/session/file', $dat);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've handled debugging code which uses $_SESSION variables by setting the relevant variables in a separate file (i.e. `session_vars.php`), then doing the following:

```
cat session_vars.php main.php | php
```

This will prepend the PHP from `session_vars.php` to `main.php` without making any changes to `main.php`, allowing you to keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

"Session" here refers to the concept used to work around the fact that HTTP is stateless between requests. PHP sessions operate by stuffing all the data from `$_SESSION` into some store on the server (defaults to files, but frequently changed around to be databases, memcache, etc.) and then issuing a "session cookie", which contains a magic unique value that the browser can re-present, prompting PHP to read all that data back.

The key point here is that it's typically operated by means of that cookie, and at the very least, by a session identifier. When executing a PHP script from the command line, you don't really have a session, per se. So the question becomes, whose session are you trying to manipulate?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way of doing this under CLI.

For the first request, you need to call `session_id()` to get the first id and save it somewhere like /tmp folder with a unique name(or save it in database or memcache etc.), for the rest of requests, before you call `session_start()` in the script, read session id from file and pass it to php.

Check  out this sample code below :

```
if($session_id = @file_get_contents('/tmp/SESSION_ID_xxx.txt')) {
  session_id($session_id);
}
else {
  file_put_contents('/tmp/SESSION_ID_xxx.txt', session_id());
}

session_start();

$_SESSION['var1'] = 'foo'; // this variable will retain the value for all following calls of this script
```